# ReactJS: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to get started building a site in ReactJS. However, when I tried to put my JS in a separate file, I started getting this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

I tried adding `/** @jsx React.DOM */` to the top of the JS file, but it didn't fix anything. Below are the HTML and JS files. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <script src="http://fb.me/react-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="./lander.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">
        React.render(
            <Lander />,
            document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var Lander = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        var info = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ";
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="info">{info}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

EDIT: I realized that I need to add `type="text/jsx"` to the script tag which includes my lander code. However, after adding this and reloading I get this warning

"You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx"

followed by this error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/.../lander.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

it seems like there is something else that I need to do in order to get in browser jsx transform working, but I'm not sure what it is.

EDIT: OOOOH do I need to host it using MAMP or something?

Comment: How are you including your "JS" file?

Comment: You need to additionally add the following script code.

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

Comment: **2019 update**:
Adding `type="text/babel"`to the script tag where I'm importing my JS file and the Babel script that @Steven mentioned in the comment above worked for me.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

UPDATE -- 
use this instead:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>
```

---

Add `type="text/jsx"` as an attribute of the `script` tag used to include the JavaScript file that must be transformed by JSX Transformer, like that:

```html
<script type="text/jsx" src="./lander.js"></script>
```

Then you can use MAMP or some other service to host the page on localhost so that all of the inclusions work, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local).

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` is commonly used because you don't have to install, run, and configure a persistent server like apache.

Comment: Works perfectly, I just added the `text/jsx` attribute value

Comment: With the update to `type="text/babel"`, use this script for transforming the JSX while in development mode: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: React 18 removed the `<script />` tag. Any updates?

Answer (score 35):

JSTransform is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html) , please use babel instead.

```
<script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 25):

Add `type="text/babel"` as an attribute of the script tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 18):

Add `type="text/babel"` to the script that includes the .jsx file and add this:   `<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>`

Comment: For version 6: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>` as mentioned [on here](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage "babel-standalone usage")

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 4):

If you have something like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token
```

You probably missed a comma in a place like this:

```
  var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {author: '', text: ''};

  }, // <---- DON'T FORGET THE COMMA

  render: function() {
      return (
      <form className="commentForm">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Qué opina" />
          <input type="submit" value="Publicar" />
      </form>
      )
  }
  });
```

Comment: Instant solution .)

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting an error like this :

> SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (107:9) 105

It could be you are missing a curly bracket

Answer (score 3):

The code you have is correct. JSX code needs to be compiled to JS:

http://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html

Comment: tried it, now I'm just getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: are you using chrome? does it give you a line number and point to specific code?

Comment: my bad, can't do line breaks without escaping them so you need to concat them with `+` ...updated should work now.

Comment: Now I'm getting this: "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: ReactCompositeComponent.render(): A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object." seems like a string isn't a valid react component

Comment: Ah I know what's going on here...you need to compile your jsx react code into javascript...are you doing that or running directly in browser?

Comment: Ideally this would be as part of some build before deploying your code.

Comment: awesome! so I thought that adding `/** @jsx React.DOM*/` to my js file and `<script src="http://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.2.js"></script>` to my HTML file would cause that to happen automatically. Is that not so?

Comment: ok i just realized that I needed to add `type="text/jsx"` to the script tag, but now I'm getting MORE errors. Will detail them above

Answer (score 3):

In my case, using `src="./<file>.js"` didn't work. Using `%PUBLIC_URL%` did the trick.

```
<script defer async src="%PUBLIC_URL%/some-file.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding in webpack, it solved the similar issue in my project. Specially the "presets" part.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?/,
            include: APP_DIR,
            loader: 'babel',
            query  :{
                presets:['react','es2015']
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using `src="./<file>.js"` didn't work. Using `%PUBLIC_URL%

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you and I have change something in my server

you might try this

```
const root = require("path").join(__dirname, "./build");
app.use(express.static(root));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root });
});
```

Comment: The original question did not use express.js; may you explain how does this fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dee Jee solution, After trying out his solution, My error never went.

I noticed(after two days of head scratch) that the browser has cached the files improperly.

- My browser wasn't able to load the preview of the cached files and status code from express was 301.
- In the networks tab of the browser dev tools, I get that those files are server from disk cache.

#### Solution

Remove the cached files. By clearing the browser history in a span of 1 hour, so that all the cached files get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Babel is a JavaScript transpiler. Babel turns ES6 code into ES5 code.

Another handy feature of Babel is that it understands JSX. Babel compiles our JSX into vanilla ES5 JS that our browser can then interpret and execute. We just need to instruct the browser that we want to use Babel to compile and run our JavaScript code.

Add attribute type="text/babel"

```
<script type="text/babel" src="./lander.js"></script>
```