# Understanding React Router params

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router

I have a static route `list` and a dynamic `user/:id`. 
Navigating between the 2 pages is giving problems **(1)** When navigating to `list` from `user/:id` it appends it as `user/list`. **(2)** When refreshing the page on `user/:id` I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-3.1.1.min.js:1` which breaks all styling.

How do I tell the router to not append if the route I am navigating to is `list`?

Why does is it throw jQuery SyntaxError when refreshing no a dynamic route?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, indexRoute } from 'react-router';

import Root from './components/Root';
import Home from './components/Home';
import ComponentA from './components/ComponentA';
import ComponentB from './components/ComponentB';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route path="/"  component={Root}>
          <indexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="list" component={ComponentA} />
          <Route path="users/:id" component={ComponentB} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Edit:** I found [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) suggest adding `type="text/jsx"` to the `src`. When I do and I don't get syntaxError now but the `js` (menu dropdowns, modals etc.) code is just not working.

```
...
    <script type="text/jsx" src="./jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="./bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="./custom.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: What version of react router are you using?

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill I am using `"react-router": "^2.8.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your links aren't defined properly. You are probably missing a `/` that tells the router that you are trying to reset the path.

```
<Link to="/link" />
```

instead of

```
<Link to="link" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved the 1st issue. Any suggestions on the second issue?

Comment: Yes your route is defined wrong.. you're missing a / on the path with your dynamic route

Comment: Sorry that is a typo (post updated) , I dont have / in the routes because as I understand it if you nest routes - parent being `<Route path="/"  component={Root}></Route>` -  all child routes will have / from the base parent route. Isn't that so? ... But i tried with  / it still throws the syntaxError.

Comment: So that error message looks like your server is hitting the catch all and returning the html file instead of a js file. Check your imports

Comment: I couldn't get jquery working when inserted via imports so I put it in the index.html at the above closing body tag `<script src="./jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @D'loDeProjuicer probably a bad path. try not to use relative paths in your html imports. instead have an absolute path. also you probably dont need jquery anyways since you are using react

Comment: it was the relative path after all... `.` :( :( Thank you