# React.js not executing in simple local hello world

Tags: reactjs

So I've been reading the basic guide and have set up a hello world file with no npm or anything, just an html file.

According to [ReactJS: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) I should have the script type set to `text/jsx` or `text/babel`. Neither work, since neither print the "hi" or do anything.

```
<html>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <div id="root">
  </div>
  <script type="text/jsx">
    ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );
    console.log("hi");</script>
</html>
```

What's going on and how do I get it to execute?

Comment: why was this question downvoted? This is something that I literally spent half an hour figuring out that I'm sure lots of people trying out react.js encounter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much digging around, here's the high level of what's causing the issue.

The code in the question is in JSX which [transpiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler) to javascript using a transpiler called Babel. The misunderstanding is that **the transpiler is not built into the web browser**. What you can do is however is import Babel at the top with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
```

and then make sure the script type is set to `text/babel` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.