# How to include custom script files in Create-react-app application

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i have created a application using create-react-app now i need to include some of the script which i have like bootstap.min.js , jquery.min.js ,script.js , 
i have placed these files inside app/styles/js ans referencing them in index.html using  script tag but if i do so i am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error in the console.

i have tried these solutions ,

[ReactJS: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token),

if i reference using CDN it works fine but script.js is the custom create hense CDN is not available

```
<body>

<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>

<div id="root"></div>


   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="../src/Styles/js/script.js"></script> //error here    
</body>
```

Comment: keep your `script.js` in `public` directory and update the path. you can't use path for  scripts from `src`.

Comment: have tried it doing so will not give error in  the console but functionality of the script is not getting applied.

Comment: check in network tab, if it is loading or not?

Comment: it is not getting loaded ..network tab is empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a `js` folder into `public` folder and put all your `js` file's into that `js` folder. And you can include that `js` file like,

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: did it but the it is not getting loaded . Nothing is showing up in network tab.

Comment: @ashish check in the source tab also. Also check your script file for any syntax error.

Comment: in the soure it is present  and there is no error in the script .

Comment: so it means your `js` file is loading fine. check console for any error. check what functionality you wrote in that file is being executed. What error comes after executing that functions.