# Importing Stockfish into React App: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am trying to import the javascript implementation of [stockfish](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stockfish) into my react app. I can replicate the above error by adding the following:

```
let stockfish = new Worker('stockfish.js');
```

I have already tried to clear my cache and I think that it has to do with how I am loading stockfish.js.  To replicate the error, all you have to do is create a new react app using create-react-app, install stockfish and add the above line.

This has been asked before (for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)) but I can't find anything that applies to my situation.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems, except in a vue app.  Here are some suggestions.

1. Is stockfish.js in your public folder of your project?  I had to manually copy stockfish.js, stockfish.wasm and stockfish.asm.js from the stockfish module folding into the project's public folder.  Not very NPM friendly.
2. Try adding '/' to the path.  That is,
   let stockfish = new Worker('/stockfish.js');
   For me this solved a bug where if I called where the if I tried to make a new worker from a component with a route of say "localhost:8080/game/12341234", the request for stockfish would be sent to "localhost:8080/game/stockfish.js" instead of "localhost:8080/stockfish.js".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, place "stockfish.js" file into your React app's "public" folder and
then you can use it like in example below

```
useEffect(() => {
  const stockfish = new Worker("./stockfish.js");
  const DEPTH = 8; // number of halfmoves the engine looks ahead
  const FEN_POSITION = // chess position in FEN format
    "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";

  stockfish.postMessage("uci");
  stockfish.postMessage(`position fen ${FEN_POSITION}`);
  stockfish.postMessage(`go depth ${DEPTH}`);

  stockfish.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.data); // in the console output you will see `bestmove e2e4` message
  };
}, []);
```

For more advanced examples, you can see [this guide](https://react-chessboard.vercel.app/?path=/story/guidebook-stockfish-integration--page)