# REACT - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : '<'

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux, jsx

I'm making a system in react but for some reason index.html is not running index.js by the following error. I've tried a lot and it doesn't work.

IMAGES:
[error in index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ6jo.jpg)
[index.html execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYH3c.jpg)

OBS: I've tried to change the type to 'text/jsx' but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Answer (score -1):

You are missing an important step, transpiling your code into something readable. JSX is just syntactic sugar on top of React for `.createElement` and is not usable without a compilation step.

The short answer is that unless you have a specific reason for trying to do this (e.g., you're trying to learn/understand), I would suggest you use an out of the box tool such as NextJS or create-react-app as they will give you a production ready solution. Alternatively, look at using [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html). I'm guessing you were trying to do something like what is mentioned in this question: [ReactJS: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token?rq=1). However, you haven't provided enough context for us to help with that or your motivation for doing so.

Diving a bit more into the details, your compilation tool (e.g., babel) will take JSX and compile it into code that plain JS can understand.

```js
const HelloWorld = ({name}) => <div>Hello {name}</div>
const MyCoolElement = () => <HelloWorld name='Bob' />

ReactDOM.render(<MyCoolElement>, document.getElementById('root));
```

becomes something like:

```js
const HelloWorld = ({name}) => React.createElement('div', null, `Hello ${name}`);

const MyCoolElement = () => React.createElement(HelloWorld, {name:'Bob'}, null);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyCoolElement, {}, null), document.getElementById('root));
```

Answer (score -2):

Are you using webpack? I dont see where the javascript libraries are included...

Answer (score -2):

Browsers can't read jsx. You can try this approach: https://dev.to/devalnor/running-jsx-in-your-browser-without-babel-1agc