503 Service Unavailable when upload create-react-app to hosting
I have tried upload my build folder from create-react-app to hosting and it return 503 Service Unavailable. The react code run well both on local and Vercel, but when I uploaded it on my hosting, it doesn't work. Here is the log return:
Log
This is my public/index.html before build
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div type="module" id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

This is my index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MyApp from './components/MyApp';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import bootstraps from './bootstrap';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./redux/configStore";

if (document.getElementById("root")) {
  ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
          < MyApp />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
// Measure performance
reportWebVitals();


MyApp.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
    unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

// Config base
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import "../assets/boxicons-2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css";
import "../assets/css/grid.css";
import "../assets/css/theme.css";
import "../assets/css/index.css";

// Config route
import AdminTemplate from "../templatee/Admin/AdminTemplate";
import routes from "../templatee/routes";
import About from "../pages/About";
import Contact from "../pages/Contact";
import { basename, history } from "../util/setting";
import Login from "../pages/Admin/Login";

// Config redux
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "../redux/configStore";
import ModalHOC from "./ModalHOC/ModalHOC";
import Loading from "./loading/Loading";

function MyApp() {
    return (
        <HistoryRouter history={history} basename={basename}>
            <Loading />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                {routes.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Route
                            key={index}
                            path={item.path}
                            element={
                                <AdminTemplate component={item.component} />
                            }
                        />
                    );
                })}
                <Route path="/about" exact element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/contact" exact element={<Contact />} />
            </Routes>
            <ModalHOC />
        </HistoryRouter>
    );
}
export default MyApp;


I'm quite new to React. Is there any possibility that the problem coming from my React code ?

this might help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100644/reactjs-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token
